# SonarQube analyze a pull request in Githib without CI

Tags: github, continuous-integration, sonarqube, pull-request, sonarqube5.1

I just discovered the SonarQube plugin for GitHub. I read that it do an analysis of a pull request. I searched how use it, but i only read Jenkins, Hudson... Can I use an do analysis of a pull request without any CI system?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The feature is provided by SonarQube scanners, so you just have to define the required properties when analysing source code. See the example documented at http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin.